# Нужно ли ставить тире в данном предложении, или же заменить его на другой знак?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Многие компании уже сейчас понимают, какими значительными будут эти изменения – и что для успешного ведения бизнеса к этим изменениям необходимо адаптироваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении  не нужно ни тире, ни запятой:

Многие компании уже сейчас **понимают (что?), какими** значительными будут эти изменения **и что** для успешного ведения бизнеса к этим изменениям необходимо адаптироваться.

Однородные **изъяснительные** придаточные связаны одиночным союзом И.

Comment: Вы хотели сказать: не нужно ни тире, ни запятой **пред И**?